# Push a document if not exist, update if exist in a nested array with mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have mongo document and when a new order appear, I need to push it or update (increment the quantity) if an order of a `part_id` already exist.

```
   {
       user_id: '13',     
       stock: [
         {
           part_id: 'P456',
           quantity: 3
         },
         {
           part_id: 'P905',
           quantity: 8
         }
       ]
    }
```

I have a tried to use `{upsert: true}` and `$inc` but could not find the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *I have a tried to use {upsert: true} and $inc but could not find the solution*

The upsert will not support in array of object, you can try 2 queries first find and second update,

Count documents using `countDocuments`:

```
let user_id = "13";
let part_id = "P456";
let hasDoc = await YourSchema.countDocuments({ user_id: user_id, "stock.part_id": part_id });
```

- Check condition if document exists then increment quantity by one
- Else push object in stock

```
// Document already exists, so increment it value
if (hasDoc > 0) {
  await YourSchema.updateOne(
    { user_id: user_id, "stock.part_id": part_id },
    { $inc: { "stock.$.quantity": 1 } }
  );
} 

// Document not exists then add document
else {
  await YourSchema.updateOne(
    { user_id: user_id },
    { $push: { stock: { part_id: part_id, quantity: 1 } } }
  );
}
```

---

**Second Option:** You can [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$cond` to check if `part_id` is in stock

  - yes, `$map` to iterate loop of `stock` and check condition if `part_id` match then add 1 in `quantity` otherwise return current object
  - no, add new object with `part_id` and quantity in `stock` using `$concatArrays`

```
let user_id = "13";
let part_id = "P456";
db.collection.update(
  { user_id: user_id },
  [{
    $set: {
      stock: {
        $cond: [
          { $in: [part_id, "$stock.part_id"] },
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$stock",
              in: {
                $cond: [
                  { $eq: ["$$this.part_id", part_id] },
                  {
                    part_id: "$$this.part_id",
                    quantity: { $add: ["$$this.quantity", 1] }
                  },
                  "$$this"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          { $concatArrays: ["$stock", [{ part_id: part_id, quantity: 1 }]] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jkR4k8SDtAu)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using an if condition, similar to yours. Wanted to find a single query but no idea.

Comment: what version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: Its mongoose 5.12, the database is cloud one

Comment: what is mongodb server version?

Comment: 4.4.5 enterprise

Comment: I have added option using update with aggregation pipeline.